# MySQL change JSON value from type 'OBJECT' to 'ARRAY'

Tags: mysql, json

Help! I have a MySQL table with a JSON column in it. A while back I pushed a change that filtered a PHP array but without resetting the array keys, so that when it got converted into JSON the array got stored as an object. I have a I need to convert this e.g.:

```json
{
  "recipients": {
    "1": {
      "name": "Alice", 
      "email": "alice@example.com"
    }, 
    "2": {
      "name": "Bob",
      "email": "bob@example.com"
    }
  },
  // ...
}
```

to

```json
{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "name": "Alice", 
      "email": "example1@example.com"
    }, 
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "email": "example2@example.com"
    }
  ],
  // ...
}
```

I'd like to do this conversion in-query if possible. I can isolate the errant rows with

```sql
SELECT data 
FROM table1 
WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.recipients')) = 'OBJECT'
```

but am stuck on doing the conversion and updating the data without affecting other keys in the JSON. Can this be done in-query or do I have to do the conversion in PHP?

Comment: Parse with JSON_TABLE(), then recompile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT JSON_PRETTY(
  JSON_OBJECT(
    "recipients", JSON_ARRAYAGG(
      JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.recipients."', k.rkey, '"'))
    )
  ) 
) AS _newjson
FROM table1
CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(data, '$.recipients'), '$[*]' COLUMNS (rkey INT PATH '$')) k
WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.recipients')) = 'OBJECT';
```

Output given your test data:

```
{
  "recipients": [
    {
      "name": "Alice",
      "email": "alice@example.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "Bob",
      "email": "bob@example.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Excellent transformation! I needed to add a group by so JSON_ARRAYAGG wouldn't combine all rows.

Comment: Yep, the test data only had one row, so I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

All credit to [Bill's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77693026/4468423) for doing the heavy lifting. I only had to make one adjustment - adding a `GROUP BY` so the aggregation did not combine all rows.

I could then use this as a subquery joined back to the main table. Since I am using JSON_SET to set the value at the 'recipients' key, the subquery can just return the transformed value without needing JSON_OBJECT (or JSON_PRETTY).

Here's the final query:

```sql
UPDATE table1
JOIN (
    SELECT
        entry_id, -- for joining back to the main table
        JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_EXTRACT(data, CONCAT('$.recipients."', k.recipients_key, '"'))) AS recipients
    FROM table1
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(data, '$.recipients'), '$[*]' COLUMNS (recipients_key INT PATH '$')) k
    WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.recipients')) = 'OBJECT'
    GROUP BY entry_id -- important or it will combine all rows into a single result!
) AS fixed
ON fixed.entry_id = table1.entry_id
SET data = JSON_SET(data, '$.recipients', fixed.recipients)
WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.routed_to')) = 'OBJECT'
```

Comment: Using JSON in a relational database makes everything so easy! (j/k)

Comment: Convenient in some respects, inconvenient in others. What's the saying? "We do things not because they are easy, but because we thought they were going to be easy."

Answer (score 0):

I found another method to extract the values that doesn't require a subquery and also runs a bit faster:

```sql
UPDATE table1
SET data = JSON_SET(
    data,
    '$.recipients',
    data->"$.recipients.*"
)
WHERE JSON_TYPE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.recipients')) = 'OBJECT';
```

By appending `.*` at the end of the desired JSON path, we can get the object's values as an array, and immediately write them back to the same path using JSON_SET.